# How can I view asp.net Azure internal errors?

Tags: asp.net, azure

After uploading my site to Microsoft Azure, server returns this text instead of my site:

> "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Where can I see what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a Azure Web App, you can enable Application Logging to write errors to the file system. You can also enable Failed Request Tracing (FREB) to see what is happening with the request. For a complete list of logging for Azure App Service (formerly Azure Websites), please see the section "Enabling diagnostic logs" here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

Answer (score 0):

Set customErrors mode to off.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx

You should really only do this for non-production sites though. You don't want your production sites disclosing error details like this.

It's not clear if your ASP.NET app is deployed to an Azure Web App or a Cloud Service. If it is a cloud service, then you should set customErrors to RemoteOnly. You can then connect to the instance using RDP and run the app locally on that instance to see error details.

If it is a web app, then setting customErrors to off will give you the details. But, I would suggest doing this in a staging environment.